# Access the fields on original req object inside axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am using axios interceptors in order to log the outgoing calls from my node.js API application. Here is the sample axios setup

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const axios = Axios.create({});

axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2));
  request.meta = request.meta || {};
  request.meta.requestStartedAt = new Date().getTime();
  return request;
});

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  const responsetime = new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt;
  const logData = {
    userEmail: '',
    userRole: '',
    userIP: '',
    sessionId: '',
    userAgent: '',
    requestMethod: response.config.method,
    requestUrl: response.config.url || '',
    requestHeaders: JSON.stringify(response.config.headers),
    requestBody: response.config.data || '',
    responseStatus: response.status,
    responseHeaders: JSON.stringify(response.headers),
    responseBody: response.data || '',
    responseTime: responsetime || '',
  };
  console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  // TODO: customLogger.log(logData)
  return response;
});
```

The userEmail, userRole are available on the request object of the route.

```
router.route('/sample-route').post((req, res, next) => {
  // userEmail, userRole, sessionId exist on req
  // Code that uses axios to make external api calls
});
```

Also, the sessionId is available on the req object (I am using express-session).
How can I access these values inside the axios interceptor?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60944390/axios-interceptor-use-express-req-object